# Samsung 870 QVO 8TB - Erigon archive

Tags: synchronization, archive-node, erigon

I read that despite being an SSD with 560mb/sR and 530mb/sW this QVO is poor at syncing Eth nodes.

I don’t need it to be a fast sync and I don’t mind it taking a while to sync and archive mode from scratch, I just need it to do it successfully and keep up to date.

Does anyone have any experience with this card and archive nodes?